# How to show value ("path") in Yii fileField?

Tags: php, html, yii

I want to show path of already uploaded file which is stored in DB. How can i show this path instead of default message "no file selected".

[image]

I had a textField where path wos loaded at update action. Now i've changed textField to fileFiled but i wish users could see the path of already uploaded file.

[image]

Can i add something to fileField $htmlOptions to show this path?

```
<div class="control-group">
    <?= $form->labelEx($model, 'path_to_logo', array('class' => 'control-label')); ?>
    <div class="controls">
        <?= $form->fileField($model, 'path_to_logo', array('class' => 'span12')); ?>
        <?= $form->error($model, 'path_to_logo'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
I wish to have this effect when path to file already exists:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set file field value due to security reasons. See [How to set a value to a file input in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html)

If you want to display current path you should output it separately is a `<span` or other HTML element.